# I am trying to project a field that is inside an object with mongoose , using the find() method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, find, projection

I'm trying to project a field that is inside an object with mongoose , using the find() method but I can't do it.

An example of the data I'm trying to find with mongoose's find() method is as follows:

```
    {
    "name": "facebook",
    "description": "description1",
    "owner": {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "63a71a743697fb56056ef511"
        },
        "publicKey": "0x6633d343235e7f1adb9574f3791645a22e646f8e"
    },
    "minimumInvestmentAmount": 1,
    "wallet": {
        "publicKey": "0x6633d343235e7f1adb9574f3791645a22e646f8a",
        "privateKey": "0x6633d343235e7f1adb9574f3791645a22e646f8b"
    }
}
```

I am trying to make the privateKey field, which is inside the "wallet" field, project it and hide it, since it is sensitive data

I tried to do this using typescript, but it didn't work:

```
async findAll(): Promise<Project[]> {
        try {
            return await this.project.find({},{wallet:{privateKey:0}}).lean();
        } catch (error) {
            this.handleException(error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use: `.find({},{"wallet.privateKey": 0})`

Answer (score 0):

Try providing the path to the field you want to project out using dot path notation:

```js
async findAll(): Promise<Project[]> {
    try {
        return this.project.find({},{ "wallet.privateKey": 0 }}).lean();
    } catch (error) {
        this.handleException(error);
    }
}
```

Side note, you don't need `return await`. You can simply just return the promise.